# Gunicorn - [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT when hitting HttpResponseredirect view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am building an api with Django Rest framework , Below is my view

```py
class UrlRedirectView(RetrieveAPIView):
    
    queryset = AwsConsoleAccess.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_id = self.kwargs['request_id']
        redirect_id = self.kwargs['redirect_id']
        aws_console_access = get_object_or_404(AwsConsoleAccess,request_id=request_id, redirect_id=redirect_id)
        aws_console_access.increment_access_count()  # Increment the click event for each clicks
        aws_console_access.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to=aws_console_access.federated_link_url)
```

I am running the app with `gunicorn`

```sh
gunicorn chilli.wsgi

gunicorn chilli.wsgi -t 0
```

Using above two commands it gives me the following error

```
2022-04-19 21:31:45 +0100] [6168] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-04-19 21:31:45 +0100] [6168] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (6168)
[2022-04-19 21:31:45 +0100] [6168] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-04-19 21:31:45 +0100] [6169] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6169
[2022-04-19 21:33:19 +0100] [6168] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6169)
[2022-04-19 20:33:19 +0000] [6169] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6169)
[2022-04-19 21:33:19 +0100] [6204] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6204
```

This issue happens only when I hit this redirect view endpoint all the other endpoint works fine.

Comment: I have the same issue, adding `--threads=2` to your gunicorn command fixes the problem for me but I don't know if this is the correct way to fix the problem. i.e. `gunicorn --threads=2 chilli.wsgi`

Comment: This works. Not sure whether this is the right way to solve

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I think it's related to some of the points noted in this article: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/.